# chapter formatting in memoir

Tags: memoir

I want my chapters unnumbered, as in this MWE. But with this configuration the `ref` link to a chapter with a `label` shows no text:

[image]

I'd like to have the chapter name there, or, better, a text I can set as when I create the label.

A second need (which I could ask in a separate question): I would like my chapters to start on verso rather than recto pages since they begin with an image that should be visible while reading the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

% suppress section and chapter numbering
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\maxsecnumdepth {none} 

% Set chapter name on the left
\chapterstyle{section}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}


\tableofcontents*

\pagestyle{ruled}

\mainmatter

\chapter{foo}\label{ch:foo}

[image on first page, should be verso]
\newpage
About this image (recto page)

\chapter{bar}\label{ch:bar}

[image on first page, should be verso]
\newpage
About this image (recto page), with a reference to Chapter~\ref{ch:foo}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one jumped in to answer I read the memoir documentation and answered my own questions.

For the link, use

```
Chapter~\titleref{ch:foo}
```

instead of

```
Chapter~\ref{ch:foo}
```

To start chapters on verso pages, use the `openleft` class option

```
\documentclass[12pt,openleft]{memoir}
```